# Weird "braces" file type - Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, types

I'm a beginner in C++ and in Eclipse, but I have a weird problem. My source and header files seem to act differently whether I imported them from someone or created them myself.

When I import a C++ file (header or source file) in my Eclipse IDE, the icon of the files on the window bar looks like this :[image]

However, when I create a file on my own (File -> New -> Source File / Header File), the icon of the files I created look like this: [image]

These files work the same as the first ones, the compiler works and the code executes properly, but it feels like Eclipse is considering the second files are in some way different from the first ones. I think this is causing some issues in the way Eclipse treats the syntax and coloring policy of my files, applying the policy to the first type of files and not to the second.

On the Project Explorer though, every file look the same : [image]

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The image for the second file type is missing.